# Debug a node.js process forked via child_process.fork in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a Node script forked using child_process's fork method using VSCode.

I have read almost all of the related docs, discussions but without any success. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

For your reference, I have posted a my sample code as a gist and is available at: https://gist.github.com/dpnishant/43096af3fecde4ec9fdea7c1d81cf543

It contains the three files: parent.js, child.js and launch.json (vscode configuration). I'm trying to setup 2 breakpoints: one at https://gist.github.com/dpnishant/43096af3fecde4ec9fdea7c1d81cf543#file-child-js-L4 and another at https://gist.github.com/dpnishant/43096af3fecde4ec9fdea7c1d81cf543#file-parent-js-L16.

**Case-1**

When I click "*Start Debuggin*g" using the "*Launch Program*" config, I'm able to hit the line 16 breakpoint on parent.js but the other breakpoint in child.js is never hit.

**Case-2**

When I click "*Start Debugging*" using the "*Attach*" config, I get the following error:

`Debugging with legacy protocol because Node.js version could not be determined (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9999)`

**Case-3**

When I start `node parent.js` in Terminal and immediately switch to VSCode to click "*Start Debugging*" using the "*Attach to Process*" config and choose the node process with the "child.js" script, I'm able to hit breakpoint on line 4 in child.js but by that time, the loop has already started and it's already late.

So my requirement is a method through which I can start my parent.js script and hit the desired breakpoint in child.js as soon as it starts execution.

Can someone point out to me where am I doing wrong? And what would be a optimum solution for my use-case?